# Userena terms of service signup

Tags: django

Userena ships with a signup form that contains a button for the terms of service.
How is this supposed to be called for signup? I couldn't find it in the docs neither in Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy, just override the basic form in the urls.py:

```
from userena.forms import SignupFormTos

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^accounts/signup/$','userena.views.signup', {'signup_form': SignupFormTos}),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('userena.urls')),
)
```

Be sure to put it in this order so Django catches the signup view here instead of in userena's urls.